# Default branch с маской (*) в TeamCity

Tags: git, teamcity

Возможно ли в строке Default branch указать не явную ветку, а маску, например, release/* ? Ветка release/* всего одна, но после каждого релиза удаляется и создается новая, с новой версией.

Проблема в том, что необходимо в момент сборки быть на коммите, который запушили, так как из этого коммита берется информация (7 символов коммита и дата). Либо как-то получить эту информацию о коммите из переменных teamcity?

Используется локальный репозиторий в build agent.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

P.S. Branch specification дописал, но проблему не решает.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю существующую архитектуру вашего огорода, но описанное вообще не проблема. Для метода Push (не путайте с  `git push`, хотя он тут имеет значение) пишется хук в репозиторий, который запускает CI, для метода Poll можно легко командами Git выяснить, какой комит был последним, а если ещё и шаблон названия ветки известен, то вообще легко.